# como enviar un token por cabezera a un webservice en swift 4?

Tags: webservice, swift, tokens

tengo un código para enviar datos a un web service que supuestamente envia el token, pero aparentemente esta mal por que el token no llega al servidor, espero puedan ayudarme.
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
     let token = "eyJ0enssnsuwew"

    let url = URL(string: "http://webservice")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: El código parece estar bien... Si ejecutas la aplicación desde Xcode, ¿dice algo en la consola? ¿El POST llega al servidor sin el _token_, o ni siquiera llega?

Comment: Espero que esto te sirva, aquí esta todo explicado: https://github.com/scaverod/HTTP-Request-Swift-4